# Google plus login functionality and composer library install

Tags: php, git, composer-php, google-api-php-client

I am working on Google + login functionality for that purpose I am referring `https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/php` url. I have done all the suggested instructions

1. Enabled google plus api
2. Set up the PHP quick-start app

In second step to run signin.php file they are suggesting to Install composer and run command `php composer.phar install`.
I have already installed Composer on my machine and it is up to date.

I am not getting how to run `php composer.phar install` command as the code cloned from `https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-php.git` does not have `composer.phar` file (only have `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files)

[image]

How do I install these dependencies as when I run `signin.php` file

Fatal error appears as `autoloader.php not found`.

I am guessing that by using composer I need to download directory from `https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.git` as this is written in composer.json file.

Let me know what should I do?

Comment: where is your composer installed? is it installed locally (phar file is in app folder) or globally? if it is installed globally, you need to just go to folder where your app is located at and do "composer install" and "composer update", if it is installed locally you need to do "php composer.phar install" and "php compose.phar update".

Comment: Did you do the full quickstart? Looking at your filestructure you are missing the composer.phar file.. Please read `Step 2` carefully again (especially point 5 and 6)